# return a lower number based on a higher base number and vice versa.

Tags: functions

So I am making an attack timeout based on a speed rating for a program that I am writing, but I am no genius when it comes to math. As it is i have a formula like so `speed(x) = x/50` the base speed rating defaults at 100, so the attack would occur every two seconds at `speed(100)`. Now what I want is for the attack to occur faster at a higher speed rating, and slower at a slower speed rating. I.e. `speed(98)` would return something higher than 2, while `speed(101)` would return something lower than 2. These numbers are just examples but the main point is that is there a formula that can return a lower number based on a higher base number, and vice versa?

Example: `speed(101) = forumla; returns x < y` and `speed(98) = formula; returns x > y` y being a constant number such as 2.

Comment: Use $f(x)=x+ke^{-x}$. Where $k$ is some constant. Choose its value accordingly. You can also use something else instead of $e$...

Comment: You just need some decreasing fuction... Try those which tend to $0$ as value grows. Like $f(x)=x+\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x}{k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do speed(x)=200/x.  Does that meet your need?

Comment: this is what happens when I do not get coffee. Yes this works.